# How to sum a value in for-each loop in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

XML File:

```
<item>
<item_price>56</item_price>
<gst>10</gst>
</item>
<item>
<item_price>75</item_price>
<gst>10</gst>
</item>
<item>
<item_price>99</item_price>
<gst>10</gst>
</item>
```

I need to sum of each (item_price*gst) using XSLT

I have managed to get the output individual by using for each loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/item">
<xsl:value-of select="item_price*gst"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My  assumption would be somewhere along the lines of but it dosent seem to be working:

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you say if you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0)? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the XSLT processor that you are using, the solution is different for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

**XSLT 1.0**

In case of XSLT 1.0, you need to use a recursive template that will keep track of the cumulative value of product (`item_price` * `gst`) for the repeating `<item>` node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="items">
        <sum>
            <xsl:call-template name="sumItems">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodeSet" select="item" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </sum>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="sumItems">
        <xsl:param name="nodeSet" />
        <xsl:param name="tempSum" select="0" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($nodeSet)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$tempSum" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="product" select="$nodeSet[1]/item_price * $nodeSet[1]/gst" />
                <xsl:call-template name="sumItems">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodeSet" select="$nodeSet[position() > 1]" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="tempSum" select="$tempSum + $product" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

In case of XSLT 2.0, it is acceptable to use `sum(item/(item_price * gst))` expression for computing the sum of the products.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="items">
        <sum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(item/(item_price * gst))" />
        </sum>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In both the cases you would get the `sum` as

```
<sum>2300</sum>
```